# removing input values when element is hidden using jquery

Tags: jquery, input

I have an div element

```
<div id=form><form id="formstuff">form input stuff</div></div>
```

that shows/hides (or toggles) when users clicks on another element

```
<div id="close"></div>
```

If `#form` is shown and user decides to input values, but suddenly decides to just click on the `#close` button to close the `#form` element without deleting the values. How would you delete all input values when the user decides to close `#form` or hide()?

Is the only way to do something like `$(this).val('');` Or is there something like `.empty();` but I don't want to remove style and such, just the text.

Comment: My question is why would you *want* to remove the input values?  Why not keep them in case the user made a mistake or wants to come back?  If redoing the form is such a struggle you can provide a "Clear" button (but should probably redo your UI)

Comment: @tandu its okay, I don't have that much information users would need to input anyways. I have a purpose for doing so. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/96FJp/

UI:

```
<form id="thisForm">
    <input type="text" value="HellO">
    <input type="text" value="World">

    <input type="button" value="wow"/>   
</form>

<input type="button" id="test">​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function() {    
    $('input:not([type=button])', '#thisForm').val('');
 });
```

​

---

To include other inputs, just put a comma on jQuery selector, do this: http://jsfiddle.net/dpRJy/1/

UI:

```
<form id="thisForm">
    <input type="text" value="HellO">
    <input type="text" value="World">

    <input type="button" value="wow"/>  

    <select id="country">
        <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
        <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
        <option value="CN" selected>China</option>        
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>                
    </select>      

    <br/>
    <input id="drink" type="radio" name="drink" value="Water"> Water<br>
    <input id="drink" type="radio" name="drink" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
    <input id="drink" type="radio" name="drink" value="Wine" checked>Wine<br/>    
</form>

<input type="button" id="test">​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function() {    
    $('input:not([type=button]),select', '#thisForm').val('');

    // radio button doesn't fit nicely to method val value clearing,
    // have to do this:
    $('input:radio','#thisForm').prop('checked', false);
 });
​
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val('');` or

```
$(this).attr('value','');
```

Comment: I guess this would be the only way huh? But since I have a submit button, I can't do something like `$(this, input).val('');` If I'm trying to remove text and file, how do I do more than one selector? I can do `$(input[type='text'])`, but how do I combine `type='file'`? Thanks

Comment: You can specify your selector like `$('form input[type="text"]').val('');`

Comment: How do I add more than one type? If i want to add text and file?

Comment: You can follow the same rule
`$('form input[type="text"]').val('');
$('form input[type="input"]').val('');`

Answer (score 0):

$(selector).empty() is used to delete all the child elements as well as the text within them. Since you wish to preserve the stye and the elements use a child selector for the parent form and set each elements value to ''.

$('#form').children().val('');

$('#form').children().attr('value','');